# Jetty 8 QueuedThreadPool thread name

Tags: java, jetty, threadpool, logback, embedded-jetty

I'm using jetty 8.1 embedded in my app. I use a QueuedThreadPool and I have an HandlerCollection with a set of ServletContextHandler. My problem is that even if a set the name of the pool I see in my logs the thread name being like [myPrefixName - 1233 /theFullEndpoint/xxx/yyy with parameters] different of course per each request received

I would like to avoid the presence of the full endpoint with parameters inside the thread name. I tried with logback configuration but as far as I know logback can only show the last x char of the thread name, not the first.
How can I tell jetty to remove the endpoint name from the thread name?

Comment: Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life), consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DebugHandler` enabled and active, disable/remove that and your thread naming will return to normal.

Comment: Ii it enabled by default? I just added a DefaultHandler but never added this DebugHandler..

Comment: Jetty 8 is EOL, what was/is default is ancient history now.  Would need to dig into the source archives to actually know the answer.  Something is setting the active `Thread.setName()`.  Traditionally, only the `DebugHandler` did that.  *Note: The Jetty project is over a thousand commits beyond Jetty 8.1.x (with 4 major versions released since, with 2 more in active development) now.*

Comment: I looked at the source code and the thread name is changed in the AbstractHttpConnection only if the the logger is configured to "debug". The simplest solution is not to log at debug level. Otherwise One can override the behaviour of the AbstractHttpConnection or write it's own Logger implementation (I need to check where isDebugEnabled method is used). Thanks for your suggestion. I would like to upgrade but, for the moment, i can't because of customer restrictions..